# Why is Flash used in some upload plugins?

Tags: jquery, flash, upload

Why do people use flash when uploading files, instead of just a normal upload box?

e.g. http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: It's so you can select multiple files at once.

Comment: You also can get infos about the files to upload before, so you are able to perform a precheck(e.g. for filetype, filesize)

Comment: You can select multiple files in jQuery too, flash is not the only one that can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash uploaders enable features that were not available for pre-HTML5 browsers.

For example:

- Multi-file upload field *(Available in **HTML5**)*
- Progress bars *(Available in **HTML5**)*
- Access to file info (extension,
  size, name) prior to upload